# How to get libdvdread4 in 20.04

Tags: package-management, 20.04, repository, mkv

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS in three PCs: two desktops and one laptop.

But, because some reason I don't know, into the Laptop there are not some DVD libraries I have in the desktops.

The libraries are related with the app `mkvtoolnix`, and the main is called: `libdvdread4`.

In the Laptop I have only the `libdvdread7` library.

The missed library doesn't appear in the Synaptic Package Manager.

From command line, when I try to download and install the missed library, I get the message:

> The package are obsolete or it cannot to be found. But, another package has a reference to it...

I don't know which could be the difference between the devices repositories. I checked it, more than twice, and... The repository lists are identical, in the three devices!!!

How can I get the `libdvdread4` library to 20.04 environment? ???

The output to the `apt-cache policy` command, in the Laptop computer is:

```
Archivos de paquetes:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=. stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=. stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.skype.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore3-stable/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-mscore-ubuntu-mscore3-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=Stable releases of MuseScore 3,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore3-stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-mscore-ubuntu-mscore3-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=Stable releases of MuseScore 3,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mikhailnov/pulseeffects/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-mikhailnov-pulseeffects,a=focal,n=focal,l=PulseEffects PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mikhailnov/pulseeffects/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-mikhailnov-pulseeffects,a=focal,n=focal,l=PulseEffects PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice,a=focal,n=focal,l=LibreOffice Fresh,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice,a=focal,n=focal,l=LibreOffice Fresh,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 100 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-otto-kesselgulasch-gimp,a=focal,n=focal,l=gimp stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-otto-kesselgulasch-gimp,a=focal,n=focal,l=gimp stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=focal,n=focal,l=winehq,c=main,b=i386
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=focal,n=focal,l=winehq,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Canonical,a=focal,n=focal,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=i386
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Canonical,a=focal,n=focal,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=amd64
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin cl.archive.ubuntu.com
Paquetes con pin:
```

That's all from that command in the laptop computer.

Comment: What's up with bold font?

Comment: Were the machines that have it upgraded to 20.04? and the one that doesn't was a fresh install, or only recently it was attempted to install it.  The library was in xenial-eoan only (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libdvdread&searchon=names) as yes it was updated in focal to 7, in groovy to 8. It's obsolete in focal and I don't see it as a requirement of `mkvtoolnix` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mkvtoolnix) so your details are incomplete or something is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: @N0rbert It's not a duplicate of that question because the libdvdread4 package is not available in the 20.04 default repositories.

Comment: I mean that `sudo add-apt-repository universe` followed by `sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix` will end with *mkvtoolnix* installed.

Comment: @guiverc the three devices are upgraded from 16.xx to 18.xx to the last 20.04.

Comment: @karel What I don't understand is why that library is too important to the app. I understand that library is intended to use with DVD devices, but... My laptop doesn't have one, so...

Comment: @N0rbert I did what you wrote and I got the same problem. The universe repository is already activated and the error message is the same. In short words: I cannot to upgrade mkvtoolnix to the last version (48.0.0) in the Laptop. In that device, I just have the 46.0.0 version.

Comment: The libdvdread4 is replaced by newer version. You can't get v4 from the 20.04 LTS repository. What is your real problem? Does mkvtoolnix work normally with v7?

Comment: I would `apt-cache policy mkvtoolnix` as you won't be use the older libdvdread4 library unless you've got unofficial/3rd party packaged `mkvtoolnix` installed .. I'd look at why as something is polluting your sources, or didn't upgrade correctly because of 3rd party sources & this could mean you have other issues that maybe more critical. Ubuntu Studio was a little more complex as it's 18.04 was **not** at LTS so used PPAs (for extended support) that upgrade instructions said mandatory purge before upgrade... and maybe you skipped the required/documented purge step'

Comment: @N0rbert Mi problem is I cannot to upgrade mkvtoolnix to the today current version (48.0.0).

Comment: @guiverc I think you're right. Maybe I forgot to erase some "extra" repository when I upgraded this device from 18.04 to 20.04, I cannot to be absolutely sure. If this is the case... What can I do?

Comment: You haven't provided the output of `apt-cache policy` which will show the source(s) of your installed and available packages which is where I'd look for information first. From there I'd likely use that information in an explore of your sources..  Refer prior comment (which wasn't spelt out but subsequent commands would depend on what was seen in my provided `apt-cache policy` output for *at issue* packages...

Comment: There is no v48 in the [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mkvtoolnix). @Juan - please add output of `apt-cache policy mkvtoolnix` to the question from all your systems.

Comment: @N0rbert I decided to use the "fast way": I delete the "extra" repository about mkvtoolnix and I back to the "standard" version of mkvtoolnix (45.0.0). Now, everything is working so fine and I don't get any error. I don't know if this is a "final" fixing to this problem, but... It works for me!!!